# Store Bot conversation - Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

how can I store the messages sent by the Azure bot and the responses of the users in CosmosDB? This was designed in bot composer

Answer (score 0):

Bot Composer is not released any package for this . you can use 3rd party package "Iciclecreek.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Database.Cosmos" more information check here : https://github.com/tomlm/iciclecreek.bot/tree/master/source/Libraries/Iciclecreek.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Database.Cosmos

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to use OnTurnAsync for this purpose ?. Similar to this link: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/5534

Comment: you want to implement middleware ?

Comment: Yes, I need something similar to TranscriptLoggerMiddleware, I need to store the conversation.

Comment: then you have to write custom middleware .. check here how to write custom middleware for bot composer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfQ9zm7K0HI